# Prevent image from going to next line

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have a working code that pulls image blobs from the MYSQL Table and shows them on my web page. It works for the most part but the problem I am running into is how to not make it move to the next line as shown in my picture below. Is there anyway to do this?

[image]

```
<?php
    $id ='1';
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","brianrob_usr","","brianrob_productdb"); //keep your db name
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id = $id";
    $sth = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $sth->fetch_array()){
    echo '<div><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'"/></div>';
    }
    ?>

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    width: inherit;
    height:inherit;
    background-image: url("007-dark-loom.png");
}
```

Comment: Looks like the CSS is the culprit. Mind posting that as well?

Comment: That would depend on the generated HTML and how wide your container is compared to the width of the images. It's impossible to say from your PHP code (and you should probably not include passwords..)

Comment: The SQL is really not going to be anything to do with this. It will be your HTML and CSS that's causing it. Please post that and show where within the layout you insert this image code.

Comment: how about adding a <br> tag ?

Comment: @PatrickSimard OP wants to make it _not_ move to the next line. As you can see from the screenshot it's already on the next line, so it's hard to see how a `<br>` would help to prevent that??

Comment: Added the CSS so you guys can work it out.

Comment: Checking the code, there should be something else between the `<img />` tags. Can you kindly post the output of the HTML that's generated?

Comment: is there any more HTML within which the images are contained? I presume you have some HTML, body, div tags etc?

Comment: there is a div tag being used yes

Comment: ok so can you show the structure please? You can do View Source in your browser to get the final output

Comment: @ADyson here is the pastebin of the output https://pastebin.com/f2ehBJM6

Comment: The divs make it go onto the next line because they're block-level elements (block level elements always create a new line unless you change their properties via CSS (e.g. set them to display:inline)). You can see the difference in this example here: https://jsfiddle.net/2of9u9or/1/ . So your simplest solution is just to remove the divs

Comment: Yep, as @ADyson just said, I'm just adding an alternative to removing the `<div>` , that is to change it to `inline-block` . Your question should had tagged CSS to get a better eye

Comment: If you want to keep all the images in the same row, just add `display: flex` to their parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Given by ADyson, Removing the  tags helped fix this issue.

```
<?php
    $id ='1';
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","brianrob_usr","Ilikecandy2009","brianrob_productdb"); //keep your db name
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id = $id";
    $sth = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $sth->fetch_array()){
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'"/>';
    }
    ?>
```